# Delete m2m through field from admin panel

Tags: python, django

I searched and could not find a way to do this. Here's my situation:

I have 3 classes:

- Publication
- Person
- AuthorOrder

The last is a **[through](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through)** class that allows me to specify the author order for a publication, as this does not normally seem possible to do.

Initially, I made `Author` a mandatory field (`blank=False`) for `Publication` and added a placeholder `Person` object to add `Publication`s to that don't have a proper author. However, a better solution seems to be to just handle missing authors in `Views` appropriately. Now, I've changed the field to be optional, but I cannot seem to set the authors to empty via the admin panel. It gives me a "This field is required." error. My guess is that this is because the `Person` is required of the `through` class, but setting the `Person` to null/empty in the admin panel does not set the through object to null/empty.

I found a workaround. One can delete the placeholder `Person` object. This unsets the through class from the `Publication`s without deleting them via cascade as they are no longer mandatory. However, this is not always a good workaround, so I hope there's a better method.

[image]

#### `models.py`

There is a lot of code, I reproduce only the minimal necessary:

```
#Publication
class Publication(models.Model):
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Person, blank=True, related_name="author_of", through='AuthorOrder')

#Person
class Person(models.Model):
    # mandatory
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=200)

# AuthorOrder
class AuthorOrder(models.Model):
    publication = models.ForeignKey(Publication)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Person)
```

#### `admin.py`

```
# AuthorInline
class AuthorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AuthorOrder
    extra = 3


# Publication
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("title", 'issue', "keywords")
    search_fields = ['title', "keywords"]
    list_filter = ['issue']

    # author list via Inline
    inlines = [AuthorInline]


admin.site.register(Publication, PublicationAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple. To the very right of the "Author order: AuthorOrder object" line, there is a small "Delete" box. Check it and save. It's small and somewhat oddly placed, so easily gets missed.